# Obtaining samples of pairs so that there is not repetition of any value in any of the combinations (R)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 X   Y
 1   1
 1   2
 1   3
 1   4
 2   1
 2   2
 2   3
 2   4
 3   1
 3   2
 3   3
 3   4
 4   1
 4   2
 4   3
 4   4
```

Now I would like to obtain *n* samples of *m* pairs (*x,y*), so that there is not repetition of any value in any of the combinations and in any of the element orders.

For example, for m=2: sample `[(1,3),(4,3)]` is not valid solution (3 repeated in y), sample `[(1,3),(4,1)]` is not valid solution either (1 repeated in first x and second y), but samples `[(1,2),(3,4)]` or `[(1,1),(2,2)]` are examples of valid solutions.

I have been trying this, but I do not know how to find and remove duplicates of x in y.

```
y <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)

df <- data.frame(x, y)

subset(df[sample(nrow(df)),], !duplicated(x) & !duplicated(y))
```

Comment: Is `[(1, 1), (2, 2)]` allowed?

Comment: yes! I am gonna update the question. Thanks

Comment: Are you really into sampling or would you rather contain all combinations that do not contain duplicated elements. Also would you like to then resample or just drop the unwanted combos?

Comment: @GWD, thanks for your comment. It is true that I didn't specified that. Users might consider whether they want to sample with or without replacement, or obtain all possible combinations before using the code bellow. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that generates a list of n samples of m elements taken without repeats from vectors x and y:

```r
unique_sets <- function(x, y, m, n) 
{
  lapply(seq(n),  function(z)
                  {
                    xs <- sample(x, m)
                    ys <- sample(unique(y[!(y %in% xs)]), m)
                    mapply(c, xs, ys, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
                  })
}
```

So now you can do

```r
y <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)

set.seed(69)
unique_sets(x, y, m = 2, n = 3)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 4 2
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 1 3
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 4 1
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 2 3
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] 4 3
#> 
#> [[3]][[2]]
#> [1] 2 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could probably start with something like this

```
res <- cbind(df[sample(nrow(df)),], df[sample(nrow(df)),])
```

and then this

```
res[,c("x1NotOk", "y1NotOk") ] <- t(apply(res, 1, function(x) x[1:2] %in% x[3:4]))
```

which will give you something like this

```
  > res
   x y x.1 y.1 x1NotOk y1NotOk
4  1 4   2   3   FALSE   FALSE
10 3 2   1   2   FALSE    TRUE
5  2 1   4   3   FALSE   FALSE
2  1 2   2   1    TRUE    TRUE
16 4 4   1   1   FALSE   FALSE
....
```

After that you drop the ones where either x1NotOk or y1NotOk (are TRUE) eg      
 `-which(res$x1NotOk | res$y1NotOk)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code like below

```
m <- 2
n <- 5
res <- replicate(n,
                 Map(c,
                     x <- sample(unique(df$X),m),
                     y <- list(sample(setdiff(df$Y,x),m),x)[[sample(2,1)]]),
                 simplify = FALSE)
```

**DATA**

```
df <- rev(expand.grid(Y=1:4,X=1:4))
```